# JQuery Sign in Sign out if statement code not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

The snippet code for a custom "sign in" and "sign out" toggle link works on old non responsive templates, but it behaves badly when on responsive template.  when it writes the html line, it actually replaces everything in the `<body>` with the `<a>` referenced in the code.

Here is the original custom code snippet used by many online for bigcommerce (non responsive theme):

```
<li class="loginLogout"><span>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var GlobalFname="%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%%";

if (GlobalFname!="" && GlobalFname!="Guest")
{
    //Customer is Logged On
    document.writeln ('<a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/login.php?action=logout">Sign out</a>');
} else {
    //Customer is not Logged On
    document.writeln ('<a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/login.php">Sign in</a>');
    };
//]]>
</script>
</span> </li>
```

I'm not sure why it would replace everything inside the `<body>` with this.... `"document.writeln...."`  So that all you get is the actual link on the page, that's it.

Here is what I've tried to implement, and it works with only "one caveat":

It doesn't change the "logout" link, until you either refresh the page, or go to another page.  The variable `%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%%` does change, but the jquery doesn't load the new link in the "else" statement.

Here is the code I have gotten to work except for this problem stated above (it is not inside the `<li>` like the first, instead it is just on its own on the page):

```
    <div id="TopMenu">
    <ul>
    <li class="loginLogout login">
        <div class="loginContainer">

        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var loginString = '<a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/login.php"><i class="icon-lock"></i><span class="narrow_hide">Login</span></a>';
    var logoutString = '<a class="logout_link" href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/login.php?action=logout"><i class="icon-lock"></i><spanclass="narrow_hide">Logout</span></a>';
    var GlobalFname = "%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%%";


    if(GlobalFname == "") {
        $("#TopMenu .loginContainer").html(loginString);
    }
    else if(GlobalFname == "Guest") {
        $("#TopMenu .loginContainer").html(loginString);
    }
    else {
        $("#TopMenu .loginContainer").html(logoutString);

    }

    </script>
```

I would appreciate any insight.  I have tried implementing `$( document ).ready(function()`, and even tried:

```
$(".login_link").hide();
$(".logoutContainer").html(logoutString);
```

putting it inside a CDATA inside the `<li><div>` doesn't help either.

but I'm coming up with a loss on how to make the final "logout" / "signout" link to show, without having to do a manual reload of the page.  Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Guess work here -- you are using some kind of a template engine that I don't recognize.  Make sure that the value of `GlobalFname` is what you expect it to be **AT THE TIME YOU GO TO USE IT**.  My first guess is that the actual login/logout logic isn't happening until later, thus you have stale data -- and stale data is why you need the refresh.  Mentioning what template engine you are using would be a big help.  *Hint: If statements work, they are a well-tested part of JavaScript with no known bugs.  It always comes down to incorrect data being given to them.*

Comment: Many thanks for the advise @JeremyJStarcher!  I am using Bigcommerce.  They have their own login/logout snippet however, it isn't editable at all, as it's in a global variable.  This used to work in their older non responsive themes, but in their responsive ones, when you want to do customizations, something has changed here, and it is still un-editable.  what's really strange, is how the first code snippet actually removes everything inside the body tag, and then inserts just the a link in the responsive theme.  so something isn't quite right there.

Comment: When the bottom code snippet is active, and you click on action = logout link, in the source code, the GlobalFname has changed back to "Guest".  So it seems like the data is refreshed, but for some reason it doesn't rewrite the link in the if statement.  Perhaps I need to pass some ajax code instead, I haven't figured out how to quite do to that yet although.  Thanks much for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got a simple code that finally works, in case anyone needs this!

```
<li class="login_logout"><a href="/login.php">Login</a></li>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var GlobalFname="%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%%";

   if (GlobalFname === undefined || GlobalFname === null || GlobalFname === "Guest") {  
       // do nothing
   }
   else {
       $(".login_logout a").prop("href", "/login.php?action=logout");
       $(".login_logout a").text("Logout");
   }

</script>​
```